# Не работает метод bind у виджетов tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пытаюсь сделать бинд на клик на canvas. Как не пытался, но функция не выполняется при клике.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind('Button-1', lambda event: print('Exactly'))
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500, fill='#FFFFFF')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли дописать ковычки [`<Button-1>`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: print('Exactly'))
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500, fill='#FFFFFF')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: спс, ну я и ретард